# How to call with credentials a .NET Webservice from Android?

Tags: android, web-services, authentication, credentials, ntlm

I´m having trouble using .NET Web Services with the Android Platform because the web service i want to consume is locked behind Windows (NTLM) authentication.
How can i to use NTLM authentication with an HttpClient request in a android application?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and i read a lot about it. But i have a "Answer" of how can you solve it.

The problem is HttpClient class because it doesnt support NTLM conecction, but, now the HttpClient api (4.2) can support it.

I read about it on Apache page, so you have to download the HttpClient 4.2 version and add it to your proyect. Use that HttpClient class and then shold works.

[You can download here:](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi)

I post it now because some people could found the solution here.

Comment: No that's exactly the right thing to do: in general if you find an old question that's out of date then either post a new correct answer or comment on the old one so the answerer can update it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4962

I don't think it's supported and doesn't seem to have any priority either since it was opened back in Nov 2009.